# Alias not running on sunos server

Tags: alias, solaris

I am trying to create alias in sunos server but no luck i am putting my code of `~/.bashrc` file !! (its code of my bashrc file )

```
alias le=`cd /Products/Logs`
If [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
./etc/bashrc
fi
```

Comment: What is you default shell?

Comment: And this line: `./etc/bashrc` should be `/etc/bashrc` (w/o the leading dot)

Comment: @RomeoNinov it’s bash shell !!

Comment: Remove the dot (as mentioned above) and try again

Comment: @RomeoNinov I did the same but not working

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you set wrong quotation marks. The first line must be:

```
alias le='cd /Products/Logs'
```

(with single quotes)

And this line:

```
./etc/bashrc
```

should be

```
. /etc/bashrc
```

And do not forget to logout then login. Or exec `. ~/.barshrc`

Comment: The `./etc/bashrc` line should be `. /etc/bashrc` with whitespace after the `.`.  The intent is to **source** that file, not execute it.